# Getting the 4 counters in other table (MYSQL)

Tags: mysql, sql

In my timesheet table there is 1 , 2 , 3 ,4 counter, my problem is the counter 2 , 3 , 4 have no result but in my counter 1 there is an output (I have here some picture.) this is the output

[image: Output 1] and

this one is my other table [image: my table]

```
SELECT id,effectiveDate,      
      if(note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and counter='1',log,'') as am1,
      if(note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and counter='2',log,'') as am2,
      if(note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and counter='3',log,'') as am3,
      if(note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and counter='4',log,'') as am4
    FROM schedules as sch
    LEFT JOIN (SELECT empid,counter,note,log,id,date FROM timesheet) tim ON sch.empid = tim.empid and sch.effectiveDate = tim.date WHERE sch.empid='16'
    AND YEAR(effectiveDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) and MONTH(effectiveDate) = MONTH(CURDATE())
GROUP BY effectiveDate
```

Answer (score 0):

Use an aggregation function:

```
SELECT effectiveDate,      
       max(case note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and counter = 1 then log end) as am1,
       max(case note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and counter = 2 then log end) as am2,
       max(case note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and counter = 3 then log end) as am3,
       max(case note = 'REGULAR LOGGED' and counter = 4 then log end) as am4
FROM schedules s LEFT JOIN
     timesheet t
     ON s.empid = t.empid and s.effectiveDate = t.date
WHERE s.empid = 16 AND
      YEAR(effectiveDate) = YEAR(CURDATE()) AND
      MONTH(effectiveDate) = MONTH(CURDATE())
GROUP BY effectiveDate
```

Comment: I think you are missing `case` within the max

Comment: I used the aggregation function already, but what is the alternative function should i used beside of max aggregation function thanks

Comment: without using the aggregate function, what function should i used to get the output

Comment: @SirGeorge . . . Without sample data and desired results, it is really hard to say.  Perhaps you want `group_concat()` instead.

Comment: Sorry, I indicate already the sample data and desired output to my explanation, what I mean why I didn't get the result on the counter 2 , 3 , 4 why only counter 1

Comment: @SirGeorge . . . Because you need aggregation functions (generally) when you are using `group by`.